# Submitting a form with jQuery after an AJAX call to a Facebook Open Graph object

Tags: facebook, jquery, coffeescript, facebook-opengraph

I've created a Facebook Open Graph object and action. It works very well and has been fully tested. The problem is that I want to submit a different form when the data is returned.

Just to be clear, there are two buttons where a user can:

1. publish an item by clicking on the "publish" button which submits the form or
2. click on "publish with Facebook" which sends the open graph object request to Facebook and then submits the same publish form from the other button on its return.

**Here's the code:**

```
$(".publish_with_fb_action").click ->
$form = $("form.publish_item")
$.post "https://graph.facebook.com/me/my_app_name:add?item=" + app.showUrl + "&access_token=" + FB.getAccessToken(), (data) ->
$form.submit()
```

Again, this code puts the item on Facebook without a problem.  The stranger thing is that when I test the same code (jQuery AJAX post) with another URL within my app it actually works and submits the form, but with this particular code, it doesn't work.

I've researched other solutions such as changing `$form` to just `form` or even `form[0]`, but still no luck.

Comment: Looks like coffeescript ???

Comment: Yeah, you're right, maybe I should have put a coffeescript tag on this question. -sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall solution involved changing the **success** callback clause to **always**.

```
$(".publish_with_fb_action").click ->
  $this = $(this)
  $form = $(".publish_item")
  $.post( "https://graph.facebook.com/me/<my_app>:add?item=" + app.showUrl + "&access_token=" + FB.getAccessToken()
  ).always (data) ->
    $form.submit()
    $this.html "added to facebook"
```